# Rotating only one of two plot labels?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have the following plot:

```
Plot1 = Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 200}];
Plot2 = Labeled[
  Show[Plot1], {Style["(a)", Black, FontSize -> 25, 
    FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
   Style["(b)", Black, FontSize -> 25, FontFamily -> "Arial"]}, {Top, 
   Left}, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

Is there a way to rotate only the label entitled "b"? I tried using RotateLabel->True within the Style box, but that unfortunately did not work.

Comment: replace "b" with `Rotate["(b)", \[Pi]/2]`

Comment: use the option `RotateLabel -> True` in `Labeled` (after `{Top, Left}`)?

Comment: @kglr Thank you! I did not realize RotateLabel applies only to the y-axis